# Django custom ID field with if condition

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am going to set the custom id with the name of "membership_num" with the increment number by 1, in every new register athlete with a prefix for each record like:

if the "**goal field in model**" is "**gym**" it should generate the ID:

description: N-Gym-Year Month Day then the number

> 1. N-G-20120700001
> 2. N-G-20120700002
> 3. N-G-20120700003

if the "**goal field in model**" is "**fitness**" it should generate the ID:

description: N-Fitness-Year Month Day then the number

> 1. N-F-20120700001
> 2. N-F-20120700002
> 3. N-F-20120700003

Models.py

```
class Athlete(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    membership_num = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, editable=False)
    goal = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=[('gym', 'Gym'), ('fitness', 'Fitness')])
```

I found and tried the following solution in StackOverflow but it does not generate the correct ID...

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if not self.membership_num:
        prefix = 'N{}'.format(timezone.now().strftime('%y%m%d'))
        prev_instances = self.__class__.objects.filter(membership_num__icontains=prefix)
        if prev_instances.exists():
            last_instance_id = prev_instances.last().membership_num[-4:]
            self.membership_num = prefix + '{0:04d}'.format(int(last_instance_id) + 1)
        else:
            self.membership_num = prefix + '{0:04d}'.format(1)

        super(Athlete, self).save(*args, *kwargs)
```

please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution based on your. It is fairly simple so I think you don't need an explanation.

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    prefix = 'N-{}-{}'.format(self.goal[0].upper(),
                              date.today().strftime("%y%m%d"))
    today_instances = self.__class__.objects.filter(membership_num__icontains=prefix).count()

    self.membership_num = prefix + '{0:04d}'.format(today_instances + 1)
    super(Athlete, self).save(*args, *kwargs)
```

**Not tested but you can try with the following**

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

#........

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    prefix = 'N-{}-{}'.format(self.goal[0].upper(),
                              date.today().strftime("%y%m%d"))
    today_instances = 0
    try:
        last_record = self.__class__.objects.filter(membership_num__icontains=prefix).last()

        today_instances = int(last_record.membership_num[-4:])
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
    
    self.membership_num = prefix + '{0:04d}'.format(today_instances + 1)
    super(Athlete, self).save(*args, *kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you "davidm" but is it possible to find the last id and increment it by +1 ? I think it is better than count, because there is a problem with count, if I delete a previous record the new record while registration generate the duplicate number same as last record.

Comment: Update check, and if the answer is correct update. Although I didn't check the solution, but will test it asap.

Comment: You are great davidm! it is working but there is a small problem with the first record while it try to get the last record from the database there is not a record it shows error, if there be a membership_num in database its working correct.

Comment: Edited the second part, test it. Please be kind upvote my answer since I put some effort to solve it :D

Comment: Error on finding the last() on the first record because there is not last record.

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'membership_num'